# Appending ul - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am appending a `ul` list and its working perfectly except when I try to append my `ul` table I assign a class of `start-dropdownClose` which is hooked to a event listener:

```
$(".start-dropdownClose").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $thisOne = $($(this).parent().attr('id'));
    alert($thisOne.selector);
    $("#" + $thisOne.selector).fadeOut();
});
```

Heres my method of appending:

```
IfpClientGui.prototype.updateFloors = function(floors){
    // updates floor list from master list of floors. 

    var ifpcg = this;
    var ifpc = ifpcg.getIfpClient();
    $("#floor_list").empty();
    $("#floor_list").append("<li class='start-dropdownClose'><a href='' onclick='return false;'>X</a></li>");

    for(var i = 0; i < floors.length; i++)
    {

        $link = $('<a href="javascript:void(0);">'+floors[i].ifpf_name+'</a>');
        $link.data("floor",floors[i]);
        $link.click(function(){         
            ifpcg.hideAllOptionBoxes();

            ifpc.displayFloor($(this).data("floor"));
            $(this).parent().find("#ifpOptionList").show();
        });

        var $floor = $('<li></li>');
        $floor.append($link);
        ifpcg.updateOptions(floors[i].groups,$floor);
        $("#floor_list").append($floor);

    }

}
```

Any thoughts or suggestions as to why this is happening?

The event listening is within an `init` class of the `ifpClientGui`.  I even tried moving the event listening outside to a `$(document).read...` but with no success.

Comment: `$thisOne = $($(this).parent().attr('id'));` - looks to be wrong because `$(this).parent().attr('id')` returns an id not the id selector. I think it should be just `$thisOne = $(this).parent()`

Comment: @arunpjohny it never even enters the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(".start-dropdownClose")` will only apply to elements with that class that exist at the time this code is executed. When you add elements with this class later on, they won't be bound to the event handler.

Try this:

```
$('#floor_list').on("click", ".start-dropdownClose"), function(event){
  // Your code ...
});
```

This means the listener is on `#floor_list` (which I assumed to be always present). Any click happening on the element will be registered and if it happened on the specific class, the function is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely attaching the event listener incorrectly. Remember, for dynamically added elements you have to use event delegation:

```
$("#floor_list").on(event_name, '.start-dropdownClose', fn);
```